# how to get the index of a point from geography?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial, geography

How can i get the index of a point which is in my LineString?
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I do have a geography type where a LineString is saved in.
I want now to get the **index** of **two points** on this **LineString**. So that I know **which** one **occurs first**.
Is this somehow possible?
Because right now i'm doing it for my self with a while loop... but it's really slow when i've got some more data in my database :/

**EDIT:** Ok, right now i'm trying to follow the solution from SQL to use CHARINDEX.
*Some more background info:*
I do have a geo point, I do have a linestring. I did get the intersecting points with a radius around my point from the linestring. Ok, now i want to try to get with the **first intersecting point** the **index** from this point on the **LineString**.
So i do have in my linestring some numbers like these patterns "1.123456 or 12.123456 or 123.123456" and my search point is also something like "1.123456 or 12.123456 or 123.123456"

*The Problem* is, that **STIntersection** gives me some different **numbers** back which are **variable** at the **fractional digits**. I thought about some string formatting, but i don't know how i should solve this. If there would be some nice regex features i think it would make my life easyier :)
I had a look through all of these [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) but couldn't find anything for my needs.

Maybe some more experienced people could help me with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the datatype is varchar used. Please see below.

You can use [**CharIndex**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64)

SELECT @document = 'abcdef12345wuerzelchen'
SELECT CHARINDEX('abc', @document)
```

Once you have got the first occurrence point, Now you can check for another.

```
Declare @position int
Set @position = CHARINDEX('abc', @document)    
SELECT CHARINDEX('wuerzelchen', @document, @position)
```

For more information you can check [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Comment: The OP's asking about `LineString`, not `String`.

Comment: thanks for the good hint. it solved my first problem but brings me to another one.

Comment: This answer is off topic. The question is to finding the numeral index of the closest geo point  on a linestring.